# how to get value using css for locators in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

We have a application where most of the elements are having  labels and corresponding input/element, we want to fetch value from each field or sometimes based on the label name we want to enter values

ex:

```
<div class="ant-row"><div class="ant-col ant-col-10"><b>UserName.</b>:</div><div class="ant-col ant-col-14"> Tiger</div></div>
<div class="ant-row"><div class="ant-col ant-col-10"><b>UserType.</b>:</div><div class="ant-col ant-col-14"> Animal</div></div>
```

How do I get value of <kbd>UserName.</kbd> , <kbd>UserType.</kbd>, here I don't want to use class since they are dynamic. I want to fetch based on text like <kbd>UserType.</kbd>

Its preferable CSS locator for selenium java , we are following page factory model.

Comment: Edit the code pasted in the question into proper HTML format so that the Xpath can be given correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below XPath expression:

```
//b[text()='UserName.']//following::div[1]
```

and

```
//b[text()='UserType.']//following::div[1]
```

**Explanation:**

- `//b[text()='UserName.']` -- This part will locate `<b>` node that contains the text value `UserName.`
- `//following::div[1]` -- This part uses the `following` axis to select the first `<div>` element that comes after the previously selected `<b>` element

**Java Code:**

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='UserName.']//following::div[1]")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='UserType.']//following::div[1]")).getText());
```

Should output:

```
Tiger
Animal
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, saved my time..struggled from last 3 days

Comment: Is there any way to fetch same thing using CSS instead of Xpath?

Comment: Glad it helped. Unfortunately, in CSS there is no direct equivalent of XPath axes like `following`